# Converting List to Set in Scala

Tags: scala, collections

I need to convert the `List` to `Set` but in order. But I am getting the set that is not in order.

```
def toset(list: List[Int]): Int = {
    var newset = Set.empty[Int]
    for (i <- list){
      newset += i
    }
}
```

Then, if I do `list = List[Int] (4,6,2,1,7)` and `toset(list)`, I will get `newset = Set(1,6,2,7,4)` instead of `newset = Set (4,6,2,1,7)`

Comment: **Sets** are unordered so your code is correct, just unnecessary. You can just `list.toSet`.

Comment: `Set`s are by definition unordered collections. You cannot have them ordered, but you can have them _sorted_ according to an `Ordering` if you use `SortedSet`. If order matters to you, `List`s and other `Seq`s are the right type.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [LinkedHashSet](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedHashSet.html). It is ordered (not sorted) Set type that pertains the insertion order.

Also in Scala you don't need a traditional for loop to convert between collection types. You can just use `to(Factory)` method like:

```
val list = List(4,6,2,1,7)
list.to(collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet)
//Returns LinkedHashSet(4,6,2,1,7)
```

You can technically use the `immutable.ListSet` too, but it is proven to be inefficient at this moment (See [here](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11752))

Answer (score 0):

Set are unordered collections by definition.

If you want a sorted `Set` you need to use the `SortedSet` Class, but it will sort the elements by an implicit sorting function depending on the element types. **It wont keep  the original list order**:

```
    val list = List[Int] (4,6,2,1,7)
    list: List[Int] = List(4, 6, 2, 1, 7)
    
    collection.SortedSet(list:_ *)
    res2: scala.collection.SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 2, 4, 6, 7)
```